# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in postman

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, php-curl

I create a curl request with PHP to call  API from another server

```
$ch=curl_init($url) ;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1) ;
$re=curl_exec($ch) ;


 echo curl_error($ch) ;
curl_close($ch);
```

but I got this error "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
I searched and try a lot to solve this problem, but they did not work.

- one strange thing is happening and that is when I run the API URL in browser address tab it works  but not work using curl in localhost , real host, postman.

what I did:

1- download cacert.pem and set the absolute path

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO,G:\Downloads\cacert.pem) 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAPATH,'G:\Downloads\cacert.pem')
```

the path works because when I set wrong path returned error about wrong path.

2-change the path of curl.cainfo in php.ini

when I set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

it works but I want secure way.

what I should do?

is some thing wrong with API server?

or my code and configuration?

why it work in browser but not in localhost , postman , real host?

I read something about ca bundle and I have no idea about what it is.
please help me.

Comment: If this is your local server, you should be fine going for http without SSL, but in case this is a public API, the owner of the API should be responsible for providing a proper SSL certificate. If this is not possible, you either should stop using this API or use http without SSL instead.